# Desde SSIS consumir un cubo SSAS

Tags: ssis, ssas

quiesiera saber si esposible consumir mediante una tarea SSIS datos de un cubo SSAS.

Cómo tendría que programarlo e ingresar los parámetros?

Gracias, saludos.-

Consumir desde una tarea SSIS un cubo SSAS

Comment: Te conectas, luego en la tarea defines los processing settings y luego defines las expresiones como cualquier otra tarea SSIS según necesites.

Comment: Realizás la conexión con el cubo, qué tarea agregás y cómo definirías los processing settings y expresiones? Gracias

Comment: Es una pregunta MUY amplia. va a depender de lo que querás hacer. Tampoco hay detalles de nada de lo que intentas y de qué problema hay consumiendo los datos. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.